# How Can I inject Entity Property Into another set of entity using JPA?

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa

I'm working on my first API project using Java JPA.
The project is based on three tables (event, phase, evt_phases); event represent vent data and phase represent preset event stages, and evt_phases links phase with event and contain two fields called `start` and `end`; those fields are containing the start date(time) and end date(time) of the phase.

[image]
This is how I created the database tables, the problem is that I currently have a API that returns the `event` contain attribute that holds array of `phases` and I'd like to include `start` and `end` from `evt_phase` table into the array of `phases`.

```
@Entity()
public class Event {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    public
    Long id;

    String name;

    @Column(name = "short_desc")
    String short_description;

    @Column(name = "long_desc")
    String long_description;

    @OneToMany()
    @JoinTable(name = "evt_phase", joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "event_id", referencedColumnName = "id"),
            inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "phase_id", referencedColumnName = "id"))
    Set<Phase> phases = new HashSet<>();

    @OneToMany()
    @JoinTable(name = "evt_resource", joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "event_id", referencedColumnName = "id"),
        inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "resource_id", referencedColumnName = "id"))
    Set<Resource> resources = new HashSet<>();

    String place;

    public void setId(Long id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public Long getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setShort_description(String short_description) {
        this.short_description = short_description;
    }

    public String getShort_description() {
        return short_description;
    }

    public void setLong_description(String long_description) {
        this.long_description = long_description;
    }

    public String getLong_description() {
        return long_description;
    }

    public void setPlace(String place) {
        this.place = place;
    }

    public String getPlace() {
        return place;
    }

    public void setPhases(Set<Phase> phases) {
        this.phases = phases;
    }

    public Set<Phase> getPhases() {
        return phases;
    }

    public void setResources(Set<Resource> resources) {
        this.resources = resources;
    }

    public Set<Resource> getResources() {
        return resources;
    }
}
```

And this is `phase` entity that I wrote

```
@Entity()
public class Phase {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    Long id;

    String name;

    @Column(name = "color")
    String backColor;

    public void setId(Long id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public Long getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setBackColor(String backColor) {
        this.backColor = backColor;
    }

    public String getBackColor() {
        return backColor;
    }
}
```

Finally, This is the middle table

```
@Entity()
@Table(name = "evt_phase")
public class EventPhase {

    @Id()
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    Long id;

    @ManyToOne()
    private Phase phase;

    @ManyToOne()
    private Event event;

    @Column(name = "start")
    LocalDateTime startDate;

    @Column(name = "end")
    LocalDateTime endDate;

    public void setId(Long id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public Long getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setPhase(Phase phase) {
        this.phase = phase;
    }

    public Phase getPhase() {
        return phase;
    }

    public void setEvent(Event event) {
        this.event = event;
    }

    public Event getEvent() {
        return event;
    }

    public void setStartDate(LocalDateTime startDate) {
        this.startDate = startDate;
    }

    public LocalDateTime getStartDate() {
        return startDate;
    }

    public void setEndDate(LocalDateTime endDate) {
        this.endDate = endDate;
    }

    public LocalDateTime getEndDate() {
        return endDate;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why not introduce a relationship between `Event` and `EventPhase` inside the `Event` entity:

```
@Entity
public class Event {
   ...
   @OneToMany(mappedBy = "event")
   Set<EventPhase> eventPhases = new HashSet<>();
}
```

You might even be able to drop the `Set<Phase>` relationship and simply use the above relation as the means to traverse from an `Event` to a `Phase` unless there is some reason you need that direct link.  It presents no harm and is obviously a short-cut if you need it.